# Disable submit button when Tags Input on textarea is empty

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, tags, submit

I created a form where users can input words in a textarea as tags and submit them as a string using JavaScript. The feature I want to add is to **disable the submit button whenever the textarea is empty *(does not contain any tags)***.

Here is what I have tried so far:

`HTML`

```
<form>
  <textarea onkeyup="success()" name="tags" id="tag-input1" required>
  </textarea>
  <p class="instruction">Press enter to add a new word</p>
  <!-- Disable Submit Button -->
  <input type="submit" id="submit" class="save" value="Submit">
</form>
```

`JavaScript`

```
function success() {
  if (document.getElementById("tag-input1").value === "") {
    document.getElementById('submit').disabled = true;
  } else {
    document.getElementById('submit').disabled = false;
  }
}
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/yjdv8oq9/)**

Answer (score 0):

I think you could check value length.
At first, try to add disabled attribute to your submit button in html.

```
 <input type="submit" id="submit" class="save" value="Submit" disabled="true">
```

Then in here is your success function code;

```
    function success() {
      document.getElementById('submit').disabled = !document.getElementById("tag-input1").value.length;
    }
```

Comment: I have tried this on my demo code but the submit button remains to be disabled even if I have added tags on the textarea.

Comment: check this its clean
https://jsfiddle.net/2ya4nzdo/

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge, that is not how disable works. Disable is a html attribute that stops user from writing data in the perticular text.
Try providing error message when value of perticular message is empty
You can use conditional statements for that